# Returning multiple values of a column

Tags: php, sql

I created a Clinic table in my database that contains the details of the clinic eg. clinicID (primary key), name, address, email, etc. I have another table called Doctor that list the name of the doctors in a clinic based on the clinicID. The problem is, in a clinic there can be more than 1 doctors per clinic. How can I show the details of the clinic in a html table that will list all the details including all the doctors that is available in the clinic?

Clinic Table

```
clinicID
name
address
email
```

Doctor Table

```
clinicID
nameOfDoctor
```

Comment: use a "list" of doctors inside each clinic "row"

Comment: either run two queries, or use something like group_concat().

Comment: Is this a UI question, a DB question or some combination?

Answer (score 0):

```
select nameOfdoctor from Doctor where ClinicId=1
```

will show you the list of doctors from clinic 1

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make two calls to collate the information in each query:

```
$raw_clinics = //sql query to get clinic data
$doctors = //sqlquery to get doctors data
$clinics = array();

foreach($raw_clinics as $c) {
    $clinics[$c['clinicID']] = $c;
}

foreach($doctors as $d) {
    if (!isset($clinic[$d['clinicID']]['doctors'])) $clinic[$d['clinicID']]['doctors'] = array();
    $clinic[$d['clinicID']]['doctors'][] = $d;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need two iterative loops to get this (assuming you want a list of clinics):

```
$clinicResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Clinic");
while ($clinicData = $clinicResult->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Insert your HTML statements regarding clinic details here
    $doctorResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Doctor WHERE clinicID = ".$clinicData['clinicID']);

    while ($doctorData = $doctorResult->fetch_assoc() {
        //Insert your HTML statements regarding doctors here
    }
}
```